# Tips for a search system with tags and sorting (questions about database design, performances issues, ...)

Tags: mongodb, search, database-design

I am developing a site around sharing texts in Java/Scala, with Play Framework 2 and MongoDB for storage.
I am currently developing the search page. There will be of course a classic textfield search, but also two types of filters :

- Tag
- Top rated / most viewed per year / month / week

For example, it will be possible to get the xxx best texts of the week among those with the tag "fantasy". If you do not see what I mean, think Pornhub. ;)

I see how to do the query, but I'm afraid of performance issues.
I'm a real noob about performance and query optimizations, and a MongoDB beginner, so I'm afraid of impact of big queries that would seek, sort and rank among tens of thousands of texts. 
Naturally, I thought of a cache system but I do not know how to implement it because each query may be different. I also thought of temporary collections updated every day at midnight (for example) with a job, but again there are too many different combinations.

So what are the techniques and "tricks" that I could use to model it? Have you any idea?  Is there a search framework designed for that ?
Or maybe I worry too much about it and that MongoDB handles very well that kind of sorting and ranking?

I hope to be clear. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

1. MongoDB is coming out with full text search soon. (v2.4)
2. You can always send data to Elastic Search or Solr at the same time it's written to Mongo. Then you can search with Elastic or Solr.
3. You can definitely tag text documents in Mongo and then index them and search. For example:

```
{ "_id" : 123, "content" : "...", "tags" : [ "fun", "cool read" ] }
```

You index the "tags" field and then you can search for "tag : 'fun'" and Mongo will retrieve that document really fast.

You didn't describe how you're doing top rated, but you could definitely write that information to the text and query on that.